# What is the motivation behind taking the min and max in limit proofs?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, definition

Why do we use $\mathrm{min}\{N_1, N_2\}$ in limit proofs? Like, what is the reasoning behind it? I always come across these minimums and maximums but I can't quite get why they are used. Can you explain to me why do we need to take the min or max of two different $N$'s or $\delta$'s?

For example, for the proof $\displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow a} x^2 = a^2$, I came across choosing $\delta = \mathrm{min}\left\{1, \dfrac{\epsilon}{2|a|+1}\right\}$. Why do we have to do this? Also, when is max or min used in appropriate situations?

The wikipedia link is right here under worked examples: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/(%CE%B5,_%CE%B4)-definition_of_limit

Comment: Easy answer: don't and see where the proof fails.

Comment: But the proof didn't fail. And I still can't quite get why.

Comment: Hard for me to say since you did not include a proof.

Comment: I included the link for everyone's reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this kind of proofs, you want to show that for each $\epsilon$ there exists a $\delta$ such that.... . Now, the $\delta$ can be small as you wish, so it might be convenient to limit it and simplify some of the algebra.

For example, if you assume here that $\delta <1$, you can say that $a-1<x<a+1$ and bound $x+a$ from above by $2|a|+1$. Now you got rid of one of the $x$s and the rest of the proof is simpler:

$$|x^2-a^2|=|x+a||x-a|<(2|a|+1)|x-a|<\delta (2|a|+1)$$

If you choose now $\delta$ to be **ALSO** smaller than $\tfrac{\epsilon}{2|a|+1}$, you get the desired $|x^2-a^2|<\epsilon$ for every $x$ s.t. $|x-a|<\delta$.